# UITextView not scrolling after drawRect

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, xcode6, uitextview, core-graphics

I called the drawRect method on a UITextView. Everything worked fine, except the scrolling part. I could scroll before I called drawRect, but now I cannot. How can I fix this?

Here is the code of the drawRect method

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TextView: UITextView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    //// Bezier Drawing
    var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(320, 0))
    bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(320, 433.97), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(320, 0), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(320, 362.81))
    bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(226, 446), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(290.15, 441.8), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(258.61, 446))
    bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(-0, 367.42), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(139.24, 446), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(60.07, 416.3))
    bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0, 239.41), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(0, 0))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(320, 0))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(320, 0))
    bezierPath.closePath()
    UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
    bezierPath.fill()

    }

}
```

This is the textView's declaration-

```
var textView = TextView()
textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: 320, height: 504)
    textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."
    textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    textView.textAlignment = .Right
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 20)
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    textView.scrollEnabled = true
    textView.editable = false
    textView.selectable = false
    textView.bounces = false
    textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

Comment: Added code @AshishKakkad

Comment: Brother I can scroll with your code ! If text is less then you can not scroll. add more text you can scroll. @KrishWadhwana

Comment: That was it... My bad. Thanks! @AshishKakkad